# How to change confirm button of Swal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweetalertjs and I have coded this for showing a popup message to users:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            let popup_shown = false;
            let cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
            for( let i=0; i<cookies.length; i++ ){
                cookie = cookies[i].split('=');
                if( cookie[0] == 'zxczxc' )
                    popup_shown = true;
            }
            if( !popup_shown ){
                    var popup_data = '{!! $output !!}'
                    Swal.fire({ html:popup_data });
                    document.cookie = "zxczxc=1; path=/";
            }
        });
```

And it works fine and perfect but I just need to know how to change the Cofirm button text which is by default set to **Ok**.

So I've searched and they said I can do this via this:

```
        swal({
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
        },
```

But this is wrong since I'm showing the popup by using `Swal.fire`.

So how can I change the confrim button text in this case?

Comment: Protips : Start with the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```

please check it is explained on their official github page
https://sweetalert2.github.io/